# Are there open source codename projects repos

Tags: codenameone

Are there any repositories with open source projects written with codename one?

I want to start a television medicine project and I don't to build it from scratch.

I haven't found any!
Thans

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources are off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Comment: My opinion is that whatever project you want to do however you will have to start from scratch. Existing projects can give you ideas and guidelines, but in the end you will still have to find your own way. I found it very useful to study the projects published in the Codename One Academy, where the implementation of some apps is shown and explained, with downloadable client-side and server-side source code. This is just my opinion though. It would be more helpful and feasible to answer specific questions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Plenty e.g. you can search for this https://github.com/search?l=Java&o=desc&p=1&q=import+com.codename1&s=indexed&type=Code and see multiple pages of apps on github.

There are some apps that we published which include:

- [Kitchen Sink](https://github.com/codenameone/KitchenSink/)
- [TODO App](https://github.com/codenameone/TodoAppMaven) - end result of [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnEyFYbdrRo)
- [Grub](https://github.com/sergeyCodenameOne/UberEatsClone/)
- [Tweet App](https://github.com/shannah/tweetapp) - this might rely on the unreleased CodeRAD 2, there's also [this](https://github.com/shannah/twitter-clone) and [this](https://github.com/shannah/RADChatApp).
- [DIYRemote](https://github.com/shannah/DIYRemote)
- [Swiftnotes](https://github.com/codenameone/SwiftnotesCN1) - Android app ported to Codename One to show how easy it is